# How to update alias column in Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, pivot

I want to update records in Postgresql DB and Laravel. 
The problem is that alias columns are not in relation with the table, but I made them in first place:

> message: "SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "nivo600" of relation "meas_kanal" does not exist↵LINE 1: update "meas_kanal" set "recordtime" = $1, "nivo600" = $2, "...↵

The function in controller:

```
$student = Stamboliiski::where('recordtime', $request->get('kanal_id'))
    ->selectRaw('recordtime')
    ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = \'text 1\') as nivo600')
    ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = \'text 2\') as razhod600')
    ->update([
        'recordtime' => $request->input('recordtime'),
        'nivo600' => $request->input('formattedvalueN'),
        'razhod600' => $request->input('formattedvalueR'),
    ])
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('fullname', 'like', "text 1")
            ->orWhere('fullname', 'like', "text 2");
    })
    ->groupBy('recordtime')
    ->orderBy('recordtime')
    ->first();
    $success_output = '<div class="alert alert-success">The record is updated!</div>';
```

Model:

```
class Stamboliiski extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'stamboliiski';
    protected $table = 'meas_kanal';
    protected $fillable = ['fullname','formattedvalue','recordtime','qualitydesc','statedesc','author','id'];
}
```

Why?

EDIT 1 after comment of @Dimitri Mostrey:

```
$student = Stamboliiski::where('recordtime', $request->get('kanal_id'))
->selectRaw('recordtime')
->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = \'text 1\') as nivo600')
->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = \'text 2\') as razhod600')
->where(function ($query) {
  $query->where('fullname', 'like', "text 1")
        ->orWhere('fullname', 'like', "text 2");
})
->groupBy('recordtime')
->orderBy('recordtime')
->first();
$student->recordtime = $request->get('recordtime');
$student->nivo600 = $request->get('formattedvalueN');
$student->razhod600 = $request->get('formattedvalueR');
$student->author = Auth::user()->name;
$student->save();
```

The error now is this:

> message: "SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "nivo600" of relation "meas_kanal" does not exist↵LINE 1: update "meas_kanal" set "nivo600" = $1, "razhod600" = $2, "a...↵                                ^ (SQL: update "meas_kanal" set "nivo600" = 1.86, "razhod600" = 9.76, "author" = John Doe, "updated_at" = 2020-04-30 10:22:28 where "id" is null)"

In this method it uses id column that I don't want, and even I don't know why it used instead using the timestamp.

EDIT 2 on reply of @Uzair Riaz

Unforchantly the problem is still here. After change the controller and model is getting success message, but nothing changes. For example if I want to change value of `nivo600` to `1` in `recordtime` `2020-04-17 00:00:00`. After I echo `$student` in `dd`:

```
App\StamboliiskiMeasCanal {#530
  #connection: "stamboliiski"
  #table: "meas_kanal"
  #fillable: array:8 [
    0 => "fullname"
    1 => "formattedvalue"
    2 => "recordtime"
    3 => "qualitydesc"
    4 => "statedesc"
    5 => "author"
    6 => "id"
    7 => "updated_at"
  ]
  #mapping: array:2 [
    "nivo600" => "formattedvalue"
    "razhod600" => "formattedvalue"
  ]
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:6 [
    "recordtime" => "2020-04-17 00:00:00"
    "nivo600" => "1.86"
    "razhod600" => "9.76"
    "author" => "Христиан Йорданов"
    "formattedvalue" => "9.76"
    "updated_at" => "2020-05-05 06:47:26"
  ]
  #original: array:6 [
    "recordtime" => "2020-04-17 00:00:00"
    "nivo600" => "1.86"
    "razhod600" => "9.76"
    "author" => "Христиан Йорданов"
    "formattedvalue" => "9.76"
    "updated_at" => "2020-05-05 06:47:26"
  ]
  #changes: array:4 [
    "recordtime" => "2020-04-17 00:00:00"
    "author" => "Христиан Йорданов"
    "formattedvalue" => "9.76"
    "updated_at" => "2020-05-05 06:47:26"
  ]
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

It seems that no update is maded...

Comment: The presented query buildup is a bit odd don't you think? Eloquent uses PDO parameter binding. There are 2 ->where method calls, 3 selectRaw, one update, groupBy and orderBy finished by the request for only the first record. Build the collection first, with either ->first() or ->get() and update this collection. You try to update a collection before it is even build (finalized). That won't work.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey you are right, but still getting simillar error. I updated the question.

Comment: `$student->nivo600 = $request->get('formattedvalueN');
$student->razhod600 = $request->get('formattedvalueR');` These two columns does not exist on your table and you cannot update them, this is the reason the errors came up. I suppose you wanted to update `formattedvalue ` field instead?

Comment: Yes, I wont to update formattedvalue

Answer (score 0):

If those are the only two aliases you are going to use, I suggest overriding the `->fill()` method in your model. Map your aliases to the `$fillable` like so:

```
class Stamboliiski extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['fullname', 'formattedvalue', 'recordtime', 'qualitydesc', 'statedesc', 'author', 'id'];
    protected $mapping = [
        'nivo600' => 'formattedvalue',
        'razhod600' => 'formattedvalue'
    ];

    public function fill(array $attributes)
    {
        foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($this->mapping[$key])) {
                $attributes[$this->mapping[$key]] = $value;
                unset($attributes[$key]);
            }
        }

        return parent::fill($attributes);
    }
}
```

Then you can update like so:

```
$student->update([
            'recordtime' => $request->get('recordtime'),
            'nivo600' => $request->get('formattedvalueN'),
            'razhod600' => $request->get('formattedvalueR'),
            'author' => Auth::user()->name
        ]);
```

Comment: `dd($student)` does not matter because **nivo600** and **razhod600** do not really exist in your table so updating them in model will be useless since they won't be updated in the database anyway. What you need is a way to manipulate both alias columns so that **formattedvalue** is updated ultimately. Do you use observers for model update and save? If yes, there might be a way to fix this particular issue.

Comment: No, I don't use observers